# CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR when trying to signin with NextAuth.js despite NEXTAUTH_URL

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, strapi, next-auth

I'm trying to setup credentials authentification with NextAuth.js as I'm working with Strapi for the backend (and Next.js for the frontend).

When I'm trying to login a user with the signIn fucntion I get the following error.

[image]

I'm working in development. I've set up .env file

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL = http://127.0.0.1:1337/api
NEXTAUTH_URL = http://localhost:3000/
NEXTAUTH_SECRET =
```

My [...nextauth].js in app/api/auth file:

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

const authOptions = {
    session:{
        strategy:'jwt'
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/auth/signin',
    },
    providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
        name: 'credentials',
        credentials: {
            email: { label: "email", type: "email", placeholder: "email" },
            password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },

        async authorize(credentials, req) {

            const credentialDetails = {
                identifier: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password,
            };

            const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + "/auth/local", {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(credentialDetails),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            })

        const user = await res.json()

        if (res.ok && user) {
            return user
        }
        return null
        }
    })
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
        if (user) {
            token.email = user.user.email;
            token.username = user.user.username;
            token.id = user.user.id;
            token.accessToken = user.jwt;
        }
        return token;
        },
        session: ({ session, token, user }) => {
            if (token) {
            session.user.email = token.email;
            session.user.username = token.username;
            session.user.id = token.id;
            session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            }
            return session;
        },
    },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

And my signin page in app/auth/signin/page.js:

```
'use client'
import {React, useState} from 'react'
import  {signIn} from "next-auth/react"

function page() {

    const [data, setData] = useState({
        email : "",
        password : ""
    })

    const loginUser = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        signIn('credentials', {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
            redirect: false,
        })
    }

  return (
    <>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post" onSubmit={loginUser}>
      <label>
        Email
        <input name="email" type="text" onChange={
            (e)=>{setData({...data,email:e.target.value})}
        } />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password
        <input name="password" type="password" onChange={
            (e)=>{setData({...data,password:e.target.value})}
        }/>
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default page
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I messed up the files directory, it should be app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

And it should be exported like so:

```
export const authOptions = (...)

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```